# не работает Button Command заданный в стилях WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Подскажите,вот у меня есть ListBox измененный с помощью стилей, и в стилях указал кнопку с привязкой к команде, так вот при нажатии на кнопку действий никаких не происходит. Стиль вида :

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="CustomListBoxItemPhone">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundLightBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Montserrat}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ColorWhiteBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Margin="5 0">
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <VisualBrush>
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <Rectangle StrokeDashArray="4 2" Stroke="{StaticResource BackgroundDarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="1"
                                           Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                           Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border}}, Path=ActualHeight}"/>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>

                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="Имя"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="телефон"/>
                        <Button Content="Отправить" Command="{Binding SendUser}"/>
                    </StackPanel></Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Команда. `SendUser = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show(SelectedUser.FirstName));`

Пытаюсь сделать при нажатии на кнопку выбор данных из строки где нажата кнопка. Подскажите как такое провернуть.

Comment: srvr4vr, можешь пример подсказать?

Answer (score 1):

У итема в листбоксе будет уже свой контекст == отображаемому им элементу коллекции.
Соответственно биндится надо к команде родителя, и передавать текущий элемент в виде параметра.

Что-то типа такого

```
<Button Margin="10,0,10,0"
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=DataContext.ShowMessage}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
  Go!
</Button>
```

Команда тоже должна быть параметризированной.

```
privater RealayCommand _showMessage; 
public RelayCommand<FooVm> ShowMessage => _showMessage ?? 
    (_showMessage = new RelayCommand<FooVm>((foo) => MessageBox.Show(foo.Value)));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: srvr4vr, у меня кнопка в самом listbox. Или я не так все понимаю.

Comment: У вас стиль описывает `ListBoxItem` - так что кнопка в `ListBoxItem`

Comment: srvr4vr. получается в стилях и написать этот binding?

Comment: ну получается так.

Comment: srvr4vr, попробую

Comment: srvr4vr, можешь подсказать, а как при нажатии кнопки получить значение ListBoxItem к которому относится кнопка.

Comment: В смысле? Итак же показал. Что ты имеешь в виду то?

Comment: srvr4vr, сделал как ты показал, кнопка нажимается, но когда я нажимаю кнопку выходит ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта". В ListBox сделал SelectedItem, берется из Model. Пытаюсь в MessageBox вывести данные из SelectedItem.

Comment: MessageBox.Show(SelectedUser.FirstName)

Comment: не знаю чего там у вас приключилось. я создал тестовую приложуху - и там все норм было. (апдейтнул ответ скриншотом)